# $Z_f \cap ((D'\setminus C)\times D_n) $ is dense in $Z_f$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Lef $f:\Bbb{C^{n+1} }\times \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ being holomorphic function defined on the polydisc $D'\times D_n$ with $Z(f)$(the vanishing set of $f$) do not have limit point on $D'\times \partial D_n$.

Prove if there is a subset $D'\setminus C \subset D'$ is dense and open,  then $Z(f)\cap ((D'\setminus C )\times D_n)$ is dense in $Z(f)$.

The book says it's due to Rouche's theorem, however I don't know to prove it rigourously.

The intuition is clear for each slice $(w',-)$ with $w' \in D'$ fixed, there are only finite intersection points, and union them on nowhere dense set is still nowhere dense. However that's not really a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on the set which is NOT in the zero set.  Above a point as you found pick any point not in the zero set.  Then pick a neighborhood of that point and use Rouché to show that when you move the $w'$ a bit, there is still no zeros there.  You'll get a whole neighborhood that way.

Comment: Hi @Jiri Lebl  , why does this fact implies denseness of the set $Z(f)\cap ((D'\setminus C )\times D_n)
$ ?

Comment: I got it thank you Jiri Lebl (if possible can you have a look at another question here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4524205/360262)